# Copy layer to own document of it's size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I usually make a mock-up of what I'm finally after and then copy each piece to a separate document. Sometimes I have close to 100 pieces to be copied. I always did this by hand using a couple of hotkeys and go through it pretty quickly. But I just did something that copied the layer immediately to a document of it's size. I just clicked on it, perhaps holding control or another key. I tried to reproduce it but I could not. This would save me to select the layer, copy it, make new document, paste layer. That's a lot, so I would be very glad to know the shortcut I just used.

Otherwise, are there any other methods to speed things up? I don't like using slices because most of the time I need the exact dimensions of the layers. Slicing it up gets tedious then too and whenever I change a image I have to edit the slice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't have any information about your version of Photoshop but i guess you have the newest (you need at least Adobe Photoshop CC 2014.2).
With the new CC 2015 Version you have multiple ways to do this.
Also you said in a comment that you just want to save the Pictures alone and don't want to "edit" them in a new Document.

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Plug-Ins then the Settings windows will pop-up.
There you have to enable the Generator (Make sure there's an mark in at "Enable Generator").
Then restart Photoshop.
All layers you want Export need a file extension (As Example if you want your Layers as .PNG the Layers need a .png at the end)
Then go to File -> Generate and enable Image Assets.
Now all files will be created in the folder your .PSD is saved in (They're saved in an seperate folder)
If you really want to have them as an PSD (as im aware it's not possible to generate PSD's with the Image Assets method) you can use an Droplet.
At first you have to create an Action with simply saving the PSD - nothing else.
Then go to File -> Automate -> Create Droplet.
At the left you have to choose where you want to save the Droplet.
It really isn't important where you save it.
Below it in the Play Window you have to choose at the Action Window the Action you just created.
At the right "Destination" you have to choose Folder and then make a Folder where all the PSD's should be saved at.
Then you open the Folder with all the Images you created before and drag them on the Droplet you just made.
Then Photoshop will do the rest and you have every single Image as an .PSD .

Actually while writing i find an easier Method for the PSD's.

Go to File -> Export -> Layers to Files.
Everything there should be really easy to understand. 
Just choose the destination and click on run.

Hope that i could help you (I'm sure that the last thing is also available in previous versions)

Answer (score 0):

Control/Right-click and choose `Duplicate Layer...`. Then select `New` from the drop down.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before asking I tried looking it up and stumbled on that. But that created a document with the same bounds.  And I did it in a single click on the layer. I wanted to select the layer with control and the next moment it was on a new document with the size of the layer.

Comment: There is no "single click" method which I am aware of. I think you are mistaken.

Comment: It surprised me too, I copied already around 10 layers to there seperate document to save them as .png. And just when I pressed the next one it opened a document with the layer added.